# How to make only forward and backword textbox focus in xamarin IOS with UItextfield?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to enter 6 digit verification code only in forward direction means left to right and for deleting right to left on UITextfield.
Use can not focus on in between text field ..if he wants to delete or change any text box value then he has to delete from the right and reach on the most left side text box.
you can see below image

[image: Verification code screen]

Comment: Do you achieve your effect?

Comment: yes , i got some idea by your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we can create a view and add a textView in it for editing like:

```
UIView containView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 200, 300, 50));
View.AddSubview(containView);

UITextView textView = new UITextView();
textView.TintColor = UIColor.Clear;
textView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
textView.TextColor = UIColor.Clear;
textView.Frame = containView.Bounds;
textView.Delegate = new MyTextViewDelegate(this);
textView.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
containView.AddSubview(textView);
```

Then we can draw six label in it for displaying the number, and six pointer line, also with bottom line like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    UILabel label = new UILabel();
    label.Frame = new CGRect(i * 50, 0, 50, 50);
    label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
    label.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
    containView.AddSubview(label);
    labelArr.Add(label);

    UIView pointerLine = new UIView(new CGRect(i * 50 + 25, 12, 1, 26));
    pointerLine.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
    containView.AddSubview(pointerLine);
    pointerLine.Layer.AddAnimation(opacityAnimation(), "kOpacityAnimation");
    pointlineArr.Add(pointerLine);
    if (i > 0) pointerLine.Hidden = true;

    UIView line = new UIView(new CGRect(i * 50 + 5, 48, 40, 2));
    line.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
    containView.AddSubview(line);
    lineArr.Add(line);
}
```

To make the pointerLine flashing when we are editing, we can add an animation to the pointerLine like:

```
CABasicAnimation opacityAnimation()
{
    CABasicAnimation opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("opacity");
    opacityAnimation.From = NSNumber.FromNFloat(1);
    opacityAnimation.To = NSNumber.FromNFloat(0);
    opacityAnimation.Duration = 0.9;
    opacityAnimation.RepeatCount = float.MaxValue;
    opacityAnimation.RemovedOnCompletion = true;
    return opacityAnimation;
}
```

At last we can do some configuration in the textView's delegate to get your effect when we try to add or delete a number. This is my delegate file for you to refer to:

```
public class MyTextViewDelegate : UITextViewDelegate
{
    ViewController superViewController;

    public MyTextViewDelegate(ViewController viewController)
    {
        superViewController = viewController;
    }

    public override void Changed(UITextView textView)
    {
        string verStr = textView.Text.Replace(" ", "");


        for (int i = 0; i < superViewController.labelArr.Count; i++)
        {
            UILabel label = superViewController.labelArr[i];
            UIView pointerLabel = superViewController.pointlineArr[i];

            if (i < verStr.Length)
            {
                changeViewLayer(i, true);
                label.Text = verStr.Substring(i, 1);

            }
            else
            {
                changeViewLayer(i, false);
                label.Text = "";
            }
            pointerLabel.Hidden = true;
        }

        if (verStr.Length >= 6)
        {
            textView.Text = verStr.Substring(0, 6);
            endEdit();
            return;
        } 
        else
        {
            superViewController.pointlineArr[verStr.Length].Hidden = false;
        }

    }

    void endEdit()
    {
        superViewController.View.EndEditing(true);
    }

    void changeViewLayer(int index, bool isHidden)
    {
        UIView line = superViewController.lineArr[index];

        if (isHidden)
        {
            line.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        } 
        else
        {
            line.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        }
    }
}
```